# Swift coreData context can't save

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

```
var error: NSError? = nil
return app.managedObjectContext!.save(&error)
```

It said "Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'NSManagedObjectContext'"

And if i delete '!'

It said "'&' used with non-in out argument of type '()'"

And finally i delete '&'

It said "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

I feel hopeless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the new syntax:

```
do
    {
       try app.managedObjectContext.save()
    }  catch let error as NSError {
          print(error)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving my problem!